# Нужна ли запятая в надписи: "С 1950(,) всегда вместе"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "**С 1950, всегда вместе**"?
Это надпись на могиле моих родителей. Я полагаю, что запятая НЕ нужна. Однако есть сомнения.

Answer (score 1):

1) В вашем варианте запятая не нужна. **Сообщение не делится на две части, это единое целое.** Если отделить первую часть запятой, то ее содержание становится непонятным.

2) Еще вариант: **Всегда вместе, с 1950 года**

В этом случае **дата будет выделена**, она дается как уточнение времени. Текст становится более интересным, эмоциональным.

Comment: Второй вариант, на мой взгляд, лучше первого: выделено главное (всегда вместе); надпись в первом варианте, начинающаяся словами "с такого-то года", вызывает ассоциацию с рекламой.

Comment: Да, верно, и деление текста на две части мне тоже хотелось оставить.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая **не нужна** (здесь просто обстоятельство времени), нужно слово "года" (если не стихотворная строка). В исходном виде выглядит по-английски: слово "год" там обычно опускается, а перенос обстоятельства времени в начало предложения (из нейтрального в английском положения в конце) сопровождается "извинительным" добавлением запятой.